# Selenium - copying and pasting XPATH from XPath Helper - "The expression is not a legal expression"

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

This is a somewhat vexing error for me. I am trying to use selenium to find elements, but occasionally I get **The expression is not a legal expression** error - even when I copy and paste the XPATH directly from the browser (and escaping all the single quotes).

Why might this be? I am copying the XPATH directly from the webpage.

Thanks for your help!

For example. According to XPath Helper: Here is the XPATH for the title of the first result in a youtube search:

```
/html[@class='guide-pinned show-guide no-focus-outline']/body[@id='body']/div[@id='body-container']/div[@id='page-container']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='branded-page-v2-container branded-page-base-bold-titles branded-page-v2-container-flex-width']/div[@class='branded-page-v2-col-container']/div[@class='branded-page-v2-col-container-inner']/div[@class='branded-page-v2-primary-col']/div[@class='   yt-card  clearfix']/div[@class='branded-page-v2-body branded-page-v2-primary-column-content']/div[@id='results']/ol[@id='section-list-961996']/li/ol[@id='item-section-948865']/li[1]/div[@class='yt-lockup yt-lockup-tile yt-lockup-video vve-check clearfix yt-uix-tile']/div[@class='yt-lockup-dismissable']/div[@class='yt-lockup-content']/h3[@class='yt-lockup-title']/a[@class='yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink     spf-link ']
```

[image: Here's how I get the XPATH]

I know this method is not necessarily general, but I was expecting it to work in the exact match case at least.

In python, my code is:

```
first_result_xpath = #the XPATH above with single quotes escaped

try:
    first_result_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, first_result_xpath)
except:
    print "Exception: Could not locate element"
```

Comment: Can you provide any reproducable example? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, will do. One sec

Comment: It's often good idea to post the actual `html` you are dealing with. That makes the debugging more easier.  On the other hand, copying xpath from webpage using browser always not good idea since the doc structure can easily be changed and invalidate the xpath copied by you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong with that xpath selector.  It looks valid, although it's not a good selector because of two problems:
1. The page structure may change, and would render the selector invalid.
2. This part of the selector, `/ol[@id='item-section-948865']`, is likely generated when the page is loaded.

A better selector you could use is as follows:

```
(//a[@class='yt-uix-tile-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2 yt-uix-sessionlink     spf-link '])[1]
```

This will return the first result of the `//a[@class=""]` selector.  Using `()[n]` will return the nth result of the selector in the `()`.

For the sake of brevity, this xpath selector also works to find the first link of a search result:

```
(//a[contains(@class,'yt-uix-tile-link')])[1]
```